# Feigenbaum logistic map

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, physics

i'm having trouble to plot the feigenbaum logistic map, i made this code:

```py
def logistic_map(r,x = 1./2,n = 1000):
   
    for i in range(n):
        x = i*x*(1-x)
    return x
r = np.arange(1,4,0.01)
x = np.zeros(len(r))

for i in r:
    x += logistic_map(i)
plt.plot(r,x,"k.")
plt.xlabel("r")
plt.ylabel("x")
```

can anyone tell what's wrong in this code, cause i'm getting the shapes wrong when i try to plot (r,x)

Comment: I think you want `x = r*x*(1-x)` and not `x = i*x*(1-x)`

Comment: Are you trying to make the bifurcation diagram?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = "plot.png"

plotlist = []

for r in np.arange(2.8, 4, 0.0001):
    x = 0.1
    print(r)
    for i in range(150):
        x = r*x*(1 - x)
        if i >= 100:
            plotlist.append((r, x))

r, x = zip(*plotlist)
plt.scatter(r, x, 0.002, marker='o', cmap='hsv', alpha=0.1)
plt.xlim(2.8, 4)
plt.savefig(filename, dpi = 1200)

# https://github.com/void4main/bifurcation-diagram
```